# Git push - node.js failed to push some refs

Tags: node.js, git, openshift

I am trying to push a node.js application, but I run into following issue:

`Total 226 (delta 25), reused 0 (delta 0)`

`remote: /usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.18.0.1/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_repository.rb:50:`

`warning: Insecure world writable dir /var/lib/openshift/532aba62493209b14e000001 in PATH, mode 040777`

`remote: Stopping NodeJS cartridge`

`remote: Permission denied - /var/lib/openshift/532aba62493209b14e000001/app-deployments/2014-03-20_02-52-39.976/dependencies/nodejs/node_modules/express`

`To ssh://532aba62493209b14e000001@myapp-test.openshift.local/~/git/myapp.git/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master`

`(pre-receive hook declined)`

`error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://532aba62493209b14e000001@myapp-test.openshift.local/~/git/myapp.git/'`

Found that could be a known issue https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1054421.

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks.